# MySQL JSON: How to check if an object in an array has two keys where the first key value is given

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.7, mysql-json

In my table I have a `JSON` field that has an object with key values where some values are arrays. Verifying if a single key exists or even if the key exists with a specified value is easy enough using `JSON_CONTAINS_PATH` and `JSON_EXTRACT` respectively, however I need to go one or two steps further.

I need to find an array element (an object) that has a specified key and value while at the same time checking if another specified key doesn't exist or if it exists and has a falsly value.

I've been trying combinations of `JSON_CONTAINS_PATH` and `JSON_EXTRACT` and `JSON_CONTAINS`

For example:

```
mysql> SET @j = '{"data": [{"a": "abc", "b": true}, {"a": "123"}]}';
mysql> SELECT * FROM db.table WHERE JSON_CONTAINS(@j->>"$.data", JSON_OBJECT('a', 'abc', 'b', true))
+--------------+
| RESULT:    1 |
+--------------+
```

The above works great, but if I try to apply the same to the second object `{"a": "123"}` it returns `0`. `0` would normally be a valid response but our current usage of `"b"` is `EXISTS && TRUE`, `EXISTS && FALSE` and `NOT EXISTS`. The first two work with the example above, but I cannot find a way to verify if `"a" = "abc" && "b" NOT EXISTS` with the current [JSON functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json-search-functions.html#function_json-contains) provided by `MySQL`

Also, I tried I also tried `JSON_CONTAINS(@j->>"$.data", JSON_OBJECT('a', 'abc', 'b', NULL))` to no avail.

Comment: Try [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=43ae37e14b125caf0b599385d6a7ec1b).

Comment: Well it took me a while to figure out what all was going on in your fiddle, but now I understand it and the logic behind it. It doesn't work for my case exactly, but I think it's a great starting point for anyone doing complex JSON queries. Thanks.